# Why is Wi-Fi called en0, like ethernet, on a Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, wifi, ethernet, network-interface, ifconfig

Linux has been my main system for years now. In Linux, ethernet hardware devices have names like `eth0` or `enp1s0` (the latter I've only seen on Arch Linux). The wireless card has always had names like `wlan0` or `wlp2s0` (again the latter on Arch). On my new MacBook Air, the wireless network is assigned `en0`, which I've read stands for ethernet. Also, there's an en1 even though I don't have an ethernet port. What does this naming convention mean?

Comment: en probably is named for **E** thern **n** et.

Comment: Right, but why is it that my wireless card is also named after ethernet?

Comment: In addition to the low level radio functionality provided by your 802.11 Wifi interface there is a built-in 802.3 Ethernet MAC since that is the primary frame format transferred over Wifi. The OS is not distinguishing this interface from the wired equivalent in its naming system.

Comment: Oh so even though my MacBook doesn't have an RJ45 input for an ethernet cable it still uses that name because the frame is an ethernet frame?

Comment: `en1` is probably referring to one of the thunderbolt ports, that use IP over thunderbolt.  Although this is a different layer 2 medium, as described in another answer, probably uses the same kernel driver.

Answer (score 23):

It's worth keeping in mind that OSX is not Linux, it is basically BSD. And in BSD network interfaces are named after the device driver that manages the interface, not necessarily based on the type of device. My guess is that the same driver supports both built-in WiFi interfaces and wired NICs on Apple computers.

You can list all interfaces using the command

```
networksetup -listallhardwareports
```

On my Macbook this lists a number of interfaces (WiFi, Bluetooth, Thunderbolt) and they are all named enX.